# WP7 should we set Visibility to Collapsed to free memory

Tags: memory, windows-phone-7, visibility

I have page A which contains `Pivot` with many pivot items. In each pivot is a ListBox. When navigating to page B, should I set `Visibility` of page A to `Collapsed` to free some memory ?

Then when I navigate to page A again, I set it to `Visible`.

According to [windowsphonegeek](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Performance-Tips-when-creating-WP7-apps)

> Visibility property - when you bring the element back on the screen,
>   by setting Visibility to Visible, the contents of the visual tree have
>   to be drawn again. The element is redrawn completely

Does "redrawn" mean "create UI again" ?

Should I do this ? Or is there a better way to free memory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should absolutely not do this.  It is unnecessary and just adds more state for you to have to manage and more code you have to write.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you navigate away from Page A and you are now on Page B, Page A is no longer taking up memory from UI elements (it still takes up whatever memory you code-behind class took up, but collapsing the page wouldn't reclaim that memory for you anyways!)

Answer (score 0):

Setting visibility to collapsed will not trigger any of the events associated with your elements. Setting visibility to collapsed does not occupy the space for the UIElements so therefore from a performance (memory) it is preferable I would assume.

Comment: Except that page A won't be rendered since the application is displaying page B. I highly doubt there's any noticeable impact to setting the visibility to collapsed.

Comment: @KooKiz so we need NOT to collapse ?

Comment: @entropy You'd need tests to be certain, but most likely collapsing won't have any effect. So no, you don't need to collapse.